# How do actually put my html file onto the internet/ browser so that random people can acess it anytime?

Tags: html, browser

I am fairly new to programming and I have made a few HTML sites but don't know what to do with them.

Comment: Find a hosting service. But service recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest https://neocities.org/, it offers free hosting and offers a free sub-domain. You get 5gb storage with a free account.